# Laser printer paper for clear wall decals? Never done anything like this and not sure what to buy

Tags: printing, decals

I want to print a few things on a clear sticker that I can stick on my walls. But I don't want it to damage the walls when I remove the stickers.

Is there any special paper I can get that I can print on with a laser printer? I see a lot on Amazon that are white but I need/want clear.

Comment: Maybe the kind of plastic used for stickers for car windows? Not sure if that will stick to a wall, though. (What kind of wall coating? Paint? Wallpaper?)

Comment: Normal paint. What would I search for to find that kind of sticker?

Comment: I found a lot in google by just googling "Laser printer paper for clear wall decals"

Comment: Ditto using the combo "clear printable car window sticker." You'll want to read the description carefully to make sure what you buy will also stick to paint.

Comment: If you let us know what (kind of) decals you'd like to print, maybe we can offer alternative solutions.

Comment: I am trying to make a clear sticker with a QR code on it for my home wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the type of paint on the walls and the type of adhesive on the decals.  In general, with normal PVA the sticker is going to end up damaging the paint either by bonding tightly and peeling it from the wall when you remove the sticker, or reacting with the paint and discolouring it over time.

Some types of high gloss enamels fare better, but in general a sticker on the wall is going to have to stay there until you decide to repaint, otherwise there will be a mark.

Paint also discolours with age due to exposure to air and sunlight. So even if you find a miracle adhesive that doesn't do anything to the paint, it will then instead protect the spot under it and once you remove the sticker there will be a noticable spot on the wall that doesn't match the colour of the rest of the wall.

That said, most clear printable sticker paper and waterslide available are for inkjets rather than laser printers.  However, Silhouette America makes a "printable clear sticker paper" that is supposedly laser printable. I have not used it myself, but you can order it from Amazon

Comment: Thank you! This helped me find what I need. Fingers crossed it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Stuff that works directly with a laser printer will have the kinds of problems described in Gwyn's answer.  If you have access to an inkjet printer, you will be in business.  There are clear, printable vinyl sheets that stick to a wall or window with static electricity.  The media will melt in a laser printer, but they're coated to accept inkjet printing.  They can be used with laser printing in a different way, which I'll describe below.

Some only work well on a smooth, glossy surface, like a window.  Others will stick to most walls as longs as they aren't textured.  Here's an [example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005GQIPKK) (no personal experience with this product):

[image]

These are commonly used for temporary signage.

This picture looks like white media because it is used with laser (or other) printing by gluing the laser-printed sheet to the cling sheet and using the cling sheet only for adhesion.  If you need it clear but laser-printed, you could print on laser transparency film and glue that to the cling sheet.

This film will stick to a window for a very long time, but I don't know how permanent the hold is to a wall.  If you need it for more than short-term use, you could investigate its longevity in practice.

Comment: These work quite well on doors, not so great on walls, especially normal PVA.  Tried them before.  Great for, say a convention, where it only needs to stick to the wall for three or four days, not so great for anything over a week or two.  On smooth surfaces they last much longer.